# How to solve this integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, ising-model

I am following some notes from a physics class on the Ising model. At some point we get to this integral
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega_B} \frac{\text{d}^Dk}{(2\pi)^D} \ln \left[ \tau + \frac{1}{D}\sum_{a=1}^D\sin^2k_a/2 \right]
\end{equation}

The next step claims that in the region of small $\tau$ this integral behaves as:
\begin{equation}
c_0 + c_1\tau^{D/2} + ...
\end{equation}
where the ellipsis denote terms which vanish faster than the second term.

The constant term is
\begin{equation}
c_0 = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega_B}\frac{\text{d}^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\ln \left[ \frac{1}{D}\sum_{a=1}^D\sin^2k_a/2  \right]
\end{equation}

Which hints that what happened was a Taylor expansion of the logarithm at $\tau = 0$. But where does the second term come from? $k$ is also small, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: (1) What is the domain of integration, $\Omega_B$? You say $k$ is small, which implies there must be some bound on $k$ in the domain of integration. (2) As a thought, it might be worth trying to do the integral for a specific value of $D$. Wolfram Alpha can do the integral in $D=1$ explicitly, although the expression is very complicated.

Comment: Taylor series in $\tau$ yields $\ln\left[\frac{1}{D}\sum_{a=1}^D\sin^2k_a/2\right]+\tau/\left[\frac{1}{D}\sum_{a=1}^D\sin^2k_a/2\right]+O(\tau^2)$ and $\tau$ is seen nowhere else in the equation. So, at a first glance, it is difficult to see how a small $\tau$ expansion could give $\tau^\frac{D}{2}$.

Comment: Could you link to these notes? Also, what is the radius of $\Omega_B$?

Comment: If the integration region $\Omega_B$ is the Brillouin zone dual to the hypercubic lattice (i.e. $-\pi < k_a < \pi$), I'm fairly sure the stated result only holds when $D<2$. More precisely, there is a non-analytic part proportional to $\tau^{D/2}$, but there are still terms proportional to $\tau$, $\tau^2$, etc. (And in $D=2$, a term like $\tau \log \tau$.)